# How do i make a main group directory name for each directories ?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
foreach (var map in maps)
{
    // This starts a new group
    var downloadDirectory = Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, htmlFiles[groupId++]);
    BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories.Add(downloadDirectory);
}
```

BaseDirectory in this is: d:\test\ImagesDirectories
htmlFiles is a List contain 35 indexs each index a directory name
froypId is int.

For example in the first index in htmlFiles i see: Sat24_Africa0
In index 1 i see : Sat24_Africa1
In index i see: Sat24_Africa2
.
.
In index 5 i see: Sat24_Asia0
In index 6 i see: Sat24_Asia1
.
.
.
.
And so on 35 directories.

In the end the List urlsDirectories that is List look like:

```
In index 0 i see: d:\test\ImagesDirectories\Sat24_Africa0
In index 1 i see: d:\test\ImagesDirectories\Sat24_Africa1
In index 2 i see: d:\test\ImagesDirectories\Sat24_Africa2
.
```

.
.
In index 33 i see: d:\test\ImagesDirectories\Sat24_South_america3

In the end i loop over this List urlsDirectories and create all the 35 directories.

```
for (int i = 0; i < BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories.Count; i++)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(imagesDirectory, BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories[i])))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(imagesDirectory, BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories[i]));
    }
}
```

But instead creating 35 directories under the base directory i want that there will be a main directory first for Europe and then under Europe to have sub directories:

Africa, Asia, Europa, Middle East, North America, Oceania, South America

And under each directory for example Africa to have the directories: Africa0 Africa1 Africa2....

So it should be like this:

```
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Africa\Africa0
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Africa\Africa1
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Africa\Africa2
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Africa\Africa3
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Africa\Africa4

D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Asia\Asia0
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Asia\Asia1
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Asia\Asia2
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Asia\Asia3
D:\test\ImagesDirectories\Europe\Asia\Asia4
```

And so on. Now i have all the names in the directories in the urlsDirectories but how do i parse them and how do i make the groups of directories ?

This is for real what i see in the BaseDirectory variable:

```
C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\ImagesDirectory
```

Then this is what i see in real in htmlFiles in index0:

```
Sat24_Africa0
```

And this is what i see now in real in urlsDirectories in index0:

```
C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\ImagesDirectory\Sat24_Africa0
```

How can i make the changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
foreach (var map in maps)
{
    // This starts a new group
    var count = "Sat24_".Length;
    var leafDirectory = htmlFiles[groupId++].Remove(0, count); // e.g. "Africa0"
    var continent = Regex.Match(leafDirectory, @"[A-Za-z_]+").Value; // e.g. "Africa"

    var downloadDirectory = Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, "Europe", continent, ﻿leafDirectory);
    BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories.Add(downloadDirectory);
}
```